# "Comment not terminated" XML parsing error in Box API response

Tags: php, rest, xml-parsing, box-api

For months I've been running the "Box Rest Client" lib by Angela R that employs the following code to parse curl responses from the box API:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($res);
```

Today, after the code loops through dozens of request/responses I generate this following error:

> ErrorException [ Warning ]: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9:
>   parser error : Comment not terminated

This happened in 2 straight attempts to run the code - and now seems to have gone away without any changes to anything.

Interested if anyone knows what is up with that?

I have put a catch for this case if its useful to anyone using this lib (for the next month or so before its deprecated by box api 2.0)

```
private function parse_result($res) {
 try {
      $xml = simplexml_load_string($res);
  $json = json_encode($xml);
  $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);     
  return $array;
 } catch (Exception $e){    
    $error = 'xml parsing error: '. $e->getMessage(). "<br>";
  return array('status' => $error );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible it is related to including two minus signs -- inside of an HTML comment.  For example:

```
<!-- this is my comment--but not a very good one. -->
```

The two dashes in the middle of the comment causes problems with the parser.